# scala: implicit conversion does not work

Tags: scala

I have a problem with `implicit` function, imported from a package.

I have a class that uses Regex to find something in a text. I would like to use it as:

```
val pattern = "some pattern here".r                                          
pattern findSomethingIn some_text
```

To do so, I define an `implicit` finction to convert `pattern` to a wrapper `Wrapper` that contains `findSomethingIn` function

```
package mypackage {                                                          

  class Wrapper ( val pattern: Regex ) {                                     
    def findSomethingIn( text: String ): Something = ...                     
  }                                                                          

  object Wrapper {                                                           
    implicit def regex2Something( pat: Regex ): Wrapper = new Wrapper( pat ) 
  }                                                                          

}
```

if I use it as

```
import mypackage._                                                           

Wrapper.regex2Something( pattern ) findSomethingIn some_text
```

it works. whereas if i use

```
pattern findSomethingIn some_text // implicit should work here??
```

I get

```
value findPriceIn is not a member of scala.util.amtching.Regex
```

so the implicit conversion does not work here... What is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need

```
import mypackage.Wrapper._
```

to import the appropriate methods.

See [this blog entry](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/implicit-methods.html) for more info, and note in particular the definition/import of the `Conversions` object.

Answer (score 3):

Brian's answer is best, though an alternative would be to use a package object

```
package object mypackage {                                                           
  implicit def regex2Something( pat: Regex ): Wrapper = new Wrapper( pat ) 
}
```

This will allow you to use your original `import mypackage._` line, as the implicit def will be in the package itself.

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html